# Persistent promiscuous mode in Debian 12

Tags: linux, networking, debian, proxmox, cloud-init

**TLDR: How do you add persistent promiscuous mode in Debian 12?**

I'm running a Proxmox server with a few virtual machines and each VM is running separate Docker containers for different tasks. Previously I've had no problem with promiscuous mode in Debian 11 cloudinit image, but Debian 12 seems to work differently. I've tested this behaviour also in Debian 12 "normal" installation, so problem is probably not cloudinit related.

For cloudinit template creation I used this guide from [OchoaProjects](https://ochoaprojects.github.io/posts/ProxMoxCloudInitImage/)

Debian 11 allowed automatic promiscuous mode with this line in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
up ip link set eth0 promisc on
down ip link set eth0 promisc off
```

Also, `ip link set eth0 promisc on` still works on Debian 12.

### So, how do you add persistent promiscuous mode in Debian 12?

Comment: Does the wireless card support monitor mode?  It needs to.

Comment: Use case here is virtual machines. So no wireless cards, only virtual ethernet connections.

Comment: Set up USB Pass Through and procure and install a USB Wireless card that supports Monitor Mode. I do that here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Debian 12 Bookworm cloudinit uses systemd-networkd**

Turns out systemd-networkd completely bypasses `/etc/network/interface` and changes in that file do not propagate. You can solve this by disabling systemd-networkd, but I suspect they have a reason to use it. Thus, I solved the problem using a modified version of a systemd service from [this post](https://alias454.com/using-a-systemd-service-file-to-control-promiscuous-mode-automatically-at-boot/).

**Solution #1**

We'll add a service to activate command `ip link set eth0 promisc on` at boot:

1. Add this service file `promisc.service` in `/etc/systemd/system/`

```
[Unit]
Description=Control promiscuous mode for interface eth0
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ip link set eth0 promisc on
ExecStop=/usr/bin/ip link set eth0 promisc off
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. Enable the service with
   `sudo systemctl enable promisc.service`
3. Reboot and `ip a` should show "PROMISC"

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
```

**Solution #2**

User [Tom Yan](https://superuser.com/users/554702/tom-yan) pointed to [systemd documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html) which provided another solution. You can add a config file in `/etc/systemd/network/` and set promiscuous mode there.

***Steps for Debian 12 cloudinit***

1. List contents of directory `/run/systemd/network/` and check files with `.network` suffix. One of them (or the only one) should contain IP address provided by your cloudinit image. Mine was `10-netplan-eth0.network`.
2. Create directory `/etc/systemd/network/<name-of-file>.d/`. Use the filename from previous step.
3. Create a file in that directory with a suffix `.conf`, any name will do. Add following in that file (use whatever network interface name you want to affect, mine is `eth0`):

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Link]
Promiscuous=true
```

4. Reboot and check network interface with `ip a`.